# Queries regarding checkpoints of Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have a few queries regarding the Tensorflow Object Detection API.

1. While training, only the previous 5 check-points are stored. I want to store more than that, say the previous 10 check points. How can this be done? (I think it should be one of the parameters of `train.proto` in  *object_detection/protos*.)
2. By default, the check points are stored every 10 minutes (600 seconds). To change this frequency, I believe it is one of these two parameters that have to be changed, please confirm which one it is:

   from `learning.py` in
   */home/user/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim*

   `save_summaries_secs=600` or

   `save_interval_secs=600`
3. While training my model (ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29), I also run the evaluation simultaneously. The latest checkpoint represented in the eval graph always lags the latest one saved in *object_detection/training* folder. For example, in the case below, the latest checkpoint shown on graph is 29.437k, while the model is already trained till the checkpoint 32.891k (and saved in the *training* folder). What is the reason for this lag (20 minutes lag) Why isn't one step (10 minutes) enough to perform evaluation on the trained model?

Comment: This post here should work i believe to change keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours

Comment: For the second point this solution worked for me: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5139#issuecomment-418963839. For example to save the model after each 1000 steps change the line (mentioned in the solution in the link) from this: "config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)" to this: "config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, save_checkpoints_steps = 1000)"

Answer (score 1):

This is for anyone who wants to configure the updated object detection API that supports TensorFlow 2

1. To save the previous 10 checkpoints, open model_lib.py and pass keyword argument max_to_keep=10 to every *tf.train.Saver* function
2. To change the frequency from 600 seconds to 3600 seconds (1 hour),
   open model_main.py and find the line that contains *tf.estimator.RunConfig* in the main function.
   Pass the keyword argument save_checkpoints_secs=3600 to the *tf.estimator.RunConfig* class.

Here is the code snippet after configuring checkpoint save frequency in model_main.py:

```
def main(unused_argv):
      flags.mark_flag_as_required('model_dir')   
      flags.mark_flag_as_required('pipeline_config_path')   
      config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, save_checkpoints_secs=3600)
```

> please note that there is a parameter keep_checkpoint_max in the
> *tf.estimator.RunConfig* class but setting it didn't affect the number of saved checkpoints for me.

Answer (score 0):

This post here should work i believe to change keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours
max_to_keep

[How to store best models checkpoints, not only newest 5, in Tensorflow Object Detection API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685923/how-to-store-best-models-checkpoints-not-only-newest-5-in-tensorflow-object-de?rq=1)

You can also refer official doc
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver